# How is fetch size controlled in akka stream alpakka slick

Tags: slick, akka-stream, slick-3.0, alpakka

The documentation of Slick cautions that for certain databases, the fetch size must be set. However in general, I wonder how to control the fetchSize with the akka-stream-alpakka-slick integration? We don't have access to the DB Action directly, hence how to do that?